# With SQLAlchemy metadata reflect() how do you get an actual table object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm just doing a bunch of selects on an existing DB.

- Don't want to use raw SQL as I may want to jump between MySQL and SQLite for testing
- Want to stick to SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression language.

I need to get a Table object so I do something like:

```
 s = select([some_table_object])
```

I've figured how to explicitly reflect a single table to get a table object:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

conn = create_engine('mysql://....')
metadata = MetaData(conn)
mytable = Table('mytable', metadata, autoload=True)

s = select([mytable])
result = conn.execute(s)

# HAPPY!!!!
```

However, this gets tedious as you have to do it for each table (I go lots of tables).  I know I can somehow use the `MetaData` class to reflect the existing DB I'm connecting to, but I'm unsure of how to get the actual corresponding Table from the metadata.

```
from sqlalchemy import *

conn = create_engine('mysql://....')

metadata = MetaData(conn)
metadata.reflect()

# How would do I get a Table instance corresponding to the 
# mytable table in the DB so I move on to HAPPY!!

mytable = metadata.no_clue_how_to_get_tables()

s = select([some_table_object])
result = conn.execute(s)
```

What's needed to replace the line `mytable = metadata.no_clue_how_to_get_tables()` to get a `Table` instance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is as simple as looking up the tables from the metadata object's dictionary of tables:

```
mytable = metadata.tables['mytable']
```

See ["Reflecting All Tables At Once"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#reflecting-all-tables-at-once) for further info.

Comment: That's simpler than expected.

Comment: Is there a way to query or filter views while using `metadata.reflect(views=True)`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are not sure what tables exist initially, you can do this query to inspect the database tables.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

# Create connection string & engine
connection_string = "sql_connection_string"
engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=False)

# Performs database schema inspection
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
```

Then you can select the Metadata from the table like the above answer states.

`Inspector.get_table_names()` returns all table names referred to within a particular schema. This does not return views. Views are instead returned using the `Inspector.get_view_names()` method. [Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_table_names)